# What is front-end class and back-end class?

Tags: java

Guys im searching about difference between composition and inheritance then I found this post somewhere.

According to the post composition is better than inheritance in code reuse.

```
class Fruit {

    // Return int number of pieces of peel that
    // resulted from the peeling activity.
    public int peel() {

        System.out.println("Peeling is appealing.");
        return 1;
    }
}

class Apple {

    private Fruit fruit = new Fruit();

    public int peel() {
        return fruit.peel();
    }
}

class Example2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Apple apple = new Apple();
        int pieces = apple.peel();
    }
}
```

change the back-end class

```
class Peel {

    private int peelCount;

    public Peel(int peelCount) {
        this.peelCount = peelCount;
    }

    public int getPeelCount() {

        return peelCount;
    }
    //...
}

class Fruit {

    // Return int number of pieces of peel that
    // resulted from the peeling activity.
    public Peel peel() {

        System.out.println("Peeling is appealing.");
        return new Peel(1);
    }
}
```

// Apple must be changed to accomodate
// the change to Fruit

```
class Apple {

    private Fruit fruit = new Fruit();

    public int peel() {

        Peel peel = fruit.peel();
        return peel.getPeelCount();
    }
}
```

// This old implementation of Example2
// still works fine.

```
class Example1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Apple apple = new Apple();
        int pieces = apple.peel();
    }
}
```

This is what I didnt get according to the post is says **"if the interface of the back-end class change, the implementation of the front-end class also change but not its interface"**.

whats the **interface** here whats the **implementation**?

THIS IS JUST MY ASSUMPTION TELL ME JUST IF IM WRONG??(MAYBE ALL IS WRONG).

Is the **back-end** class the interface because **front-end** class depends on it?
Is the **implementation** of front-end class the implementation code inside the front-end class?
Is **front-end** class also an **interface** because the code inside Example **depends** on it?

Are they **lousely coupled** because change to **back-end interface** didnt make change to **front-end interface**? So the code that depends on **front-end interface** still works.

If I use inheritance instead is subclass tightly coupled in superclass? Because change to superclass will also change to subclass so  code that depends on subclass will may not work.

Wny inheritance is weak encapsulation.

Comment: If you could link the article in question it might help us understand the point being made.

Comment: You say this is an example comparing inheritance and composition, but there is no inheritance...please post source.

Comment: Source: http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh.html

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://yuml.me/50f06bed) is the intuitive inheritance relationship which *should* be going on between Apple and Fruit. However, this is *not* what the above example has done.

[image]

The above example is using composition, which means that `Fruit` is *part of* `Apple` (see uml [here](http://yuml.me/6efd59d1)). This is pretty counter-intuitive! In this case, both `Fruit` and `Apple` has separate implementations of peel. The implementation of `peel()` in `Apple` uses `Fruit.peel()`.

[image]

I think the point being made is that if `Apple` uses a composition relationship with `Fruit`, then it's implementation *can* be independent of Fruit. For example, instead of using `Fruit.peel()` to get the count for `Apple.peel()`, I could use some other implementation. But if `Apple` inherits peel from `Fruit`, then a change in `Fruit` also changes `Apple`. Therefore `Apple` is not independent of `Fruit`, so we say it is tightly coupled.

It's a bad example in a couple of ways, 1) we all know that an apple *is a*  fruit, so inheritance seems like the most correct implementation. 2) Inheritance appears to be the most *DRY* way to implement things, since using composition requires you to correct the `Apple` class to do the same thing as `Fruit` when the change is made to `Fruit.peel()`.

EDIT: Having read the article, I feel the main point is to outline the pitfalls of using inheritance.  There is nothing wrong with using inheritance *appropriately*. Using it simply for the sake of code reuse could cause problems if the child classes *don't really* inherit behaviour from the super class.

**To answer your questions!**

> Is the back-end class the interface because front-end class depends on
>   it?

Close enough. All classes have an "interface." This doesn't mean they literally have `implements IFruit` in their class declaration, it just refers to the *shape* of the object - what methods that objects has, regardless of how those methods work.

> Is the implementation of front-end class the implementation code
>   inside the front-end class?

Roughly, yes. The actual logic of the code which makes up the body of the methods in a class is that class' implementation.

> Is front-end class also an interface because the code inside Example
>   depends on it?

Pretty much. `Apple` has an interface, implicitly, just like any other class. If `Example` uses the `Apple` class, then it can only do so by using methods which are part of the interface.

> Are they lousely coupled because change to back-end interface didnt
>   make change to front-end interface?

Yeah, that's one way of using the phrase "loosely coupled."

> If I use inheritance instead is subclass tightly coupled in
>   superclass? Because change to superclass will also change to subclass
>   so code that depends on subclass will may not work.

Yes that's right. The two classes are tightly coupled in that they are their behaviour is not entirely encapsulated in each separate class. This isn't always wrong, it depends on the situation.

> Wny inheritance is weak encapsulation.[sic]

Because the behaviour is shared between the superclass and the subclass.

Comment: +1 Yes, very bad example, it shouldn't be #1 on Google.  BTW what UML tool are you using?

Comment: I am using [yuml](http://yuml.me/). But it got mucked up when I edited the post and I had to add them in again.

Comment: I do not think it's a bad example. It's so clear that apple and fruit have an inheritance relation that it can even better show the difference in how you would do it in a way that uses composition. The dry-principle is broken, but the author is trying to show the differences in concept between composition and inheritance by sticking to one example familiar to all and shows the concepts.  http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html

Comment: @GarrettHall Do you know any good example for Inheritance V Composition learning which I can refer?  The same example is present here as well which OP mentioned : https://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh3.html